# Domain only works as https (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https, url-rewriting

I have the following domain and it only loads over "https:" correctly

I get the following error when on the domain without https: Internal Error: Missing Template ERR_CONNECT_FAIL

Any tips or possible direction as to where to look would be appreciated.  Trying a lot of different things and no results so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # First rewrite to HTTPS:
    # Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
    # the subsequent rule will catch it.
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    # Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It will just redirect users to the ssl page. Saving your site temporarily.